# How to disable all the controls on the page after the countdown timer stops in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have tried to disable the next button in the following code but its not working....pls help...

```
     protected void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentTime = CurrentTime.AddSeconds(-1);
        LblTime.Text = "Time Left: " + CurrentTime.TimeOfDay;

        if (CurrentTime.TimeOfDay == DateTime.MinValue.TimeOfDay)
        {
            LblTime.Text = "Oops!! Time Up";         

            timer1.Enabled = false;

            btnnext.Enabled = false;

        }
```

Comment: Are you sure control comes in the if block which disables btnnext?

Comment: Where is `CurrentTime` being stored between postbacks?

Comment: @Adil...yes the control reaches over there but still the button is not getting disabled

Comment: You can use javascript's `setTimeout()`, `clearTimeout(timeoutId)` pair to start/stop the timer and can disable the controls at client-side.

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to use timer on server side in asp.net. you are on the wrong track. unless you are using updatepanel control

Comment: Thanks all for your answers ..but i came to know that the next button was not in the UpdatePanel and that is why it was not getting disabled.

Comment: @CoDe aDDict we can use timer in server side through ajax.I update my Datagrid through timer using updatepanel and set timer_tick to updatepanel trigger.

Comment: well. I am amazed to hear that (:. you are right. answer edited... thanks